# Por qué me sale este error al querer instalar cordova facebook 4 en macOS?

Tags: ionic, ios, macos

[image]

Todos los plugins me instalan, pero menos de facebook. Algunos detalles logré solucionar pero hasta ahora me sigue saliendo el error de "You cannot run Cocoapods as root" ayuda por favor!

Comment: [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6Bbc.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6Bbc.jpg) Al ejecutar sin el sudo me sale este error. Es a la carpeta de mi proyecto que debo otorgar permisos?

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Procura que la información que incluyas sea texto, que no siempre es trivial ver imágenes en las preguntas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error del terminal se debe al terminal que estas usando. Considera usar otro terminal o una sesion con UTF-8 activado (revisa el archivo `~/.profile` la variable `LANG`)

Al ejecutar ionic con `sudo` el script se ejecuta como root, y al instalar las dependencias de Cocoapods no se puede ejecutar bajo root. Considera tratar de no usar `sudo` para el comando. La carpeta debe permitir escritura para tu usuario actual, puedes intentar cambiar el propietario de la carpeta a tu usuario:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /path/to/folder
```